# Binary Exponentiation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Find below my implementation for binary exponentiation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int fast_exponentiation(int base, int pow) {
    unsigned int result; // variable to store intermediaries

    if (pow == 1) {
        return base;
    }
    else if (pow == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    result = fast_exponentiation(base, floor(pow/2));

    // even power
    if (pow % 2 == 0) {
        return result * result; 
    }
    // odd power
    else {
        return result * base * result;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num, answer, p;
    cout <<  "Enter the base: ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "Enter power: "; 
    cin >> p;

    answer = fast_exponentiation(num, p);
    cout << answer <<  endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I ran this for inputs num= 3 and pow = 20 I get -808182895, a negative number. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code? Can I get some help?

Comment: does it have to do with the data type? am i out of range? if so how do i rewrite it to include large powers of 3?

Answer (score 0):

Value of 3^20 exceeds max possible int value 2^31, so you have got overflow. The simplest way to overcome this limit is using `long long` data type to provide possiblity for calculations upto power 39 (near 2^63)

For larger powers one need long number arithmetics - boost multi-precision, GMP etc